# Не работает quicksort

Tags: алгоритм, pascal, freepascal

Здраствуйте, столкнулся с такой проблемой: пишу сортировку на pascal (quicksort) и вроде бы все правильно (на мой взгляд), да вот только идет постоянно зацикливание (скорее всего проблема в самой рекурсии, т.к. без нее все работает без зацикливания).
Вот код(с доп.выводом моих индексов i и j):

```
    program quickSort;

 {const blcok}
const
 n = 7;

 {type block}
type
 massive = array[1..n] of integer;

 {procedure block}
procedure input_arr(var arr:massive);
var
 i: integer;
begin
 writeln('vvedite elementi massiva: ');
for i := 1 to n do
  begin 
   read(arr[i]);
  end;
end;

procedure quicksort(var arr : massive);
var
 lol1, lol2 : integer;
procedure sort(var l,r: integer); {body of my sort, include quicksort, but not declare it}
var
 i,j,x,ch,g: integer;
begin
i := l;
j := r;
ch := (l+r) div 2;
x := arr[ch];
repeat
while arr[i] < x do i := i + 1;
while arr[j] > x do j := j - 1;
if i <= j then {if i <= j then} 
 begin
  if arr[i] > arr[j] then
   begin
    arr[i] := arr[i] xor arr[j];
    arr[j] := arr[i] xor arr[j];
    arr[i] := arr[i] xor arr[j];
   end;
 end;
 i := 1 + 1; j := j - 1;
 for g := 1 to n do
  begin
  write(arr[g], ' ');
  end;
  write('nashi indexi: ');
  write('eto nashe i: ', i, ' ');
  write('eto nashe j: ', j);
  writeln;
until i >= j;
if l < j then sort(l,j);
if i < r then sort(i,r);
end;
begin
lol1 := 1;
lol2 := 7;
sort(lol1,lol2);
end;

{var block}
var
 i,j,mstart,mend: integer;
 arr1 : massive;

BEGIN
input_arr(arr1);

write('eto nash massiv isnachalno: ');
for i:= 1 to n do
 write(arr1[i], ' ');
 writeln;

 mstart := 1;
 mend := 7;
quicksort(arr1);

write('eto nash OTSORTIROVANIY massiv: ');
for i:= 1 to n do
  write(arr1[i], ' ');
END.
```

Допустим, мы ввели такие входные данные :

```
7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

Тогда на выходе мы получаем вот что:

```
vvedite elementi massiva: 
eto nash massiv isnachalno: 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 
1 6 5 4 3 2 7 nashi indexi: eto nashe i: 2 eto nashe j: 6
1 2 5 4 3 6 7 nashi indexi: eto nashe i: 2 eto nashe j: 5
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 nashi indexi: eto nashe i: 2 eto nashe j: 4
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 nashi indexi: eto nashe i: 2 eto nashe j: 3
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 nashi indexi: eto nashe i: 2 eto nashe j: 2
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 nashi indexi: eto nashe i: 2 eto nashe j: 0
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 nashi indexi: eto nashe i: 2 eto nashe j: 3
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 nashi indexi: eto nashe i: 2 eto nashe j: 2
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 nashi indexi: eto nashe i: 2 eto nashe j: 3
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 nashi indexi: eto nashe i: 2 eto nashe j: 2
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 nashi indexi: eto nashe i: 2 eto nashe j: 3
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 nashi indexi: eto nashe i: 2 eto nashe j: 2
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 nashi indexi: eto nashe i: 2 eto nashe j: 3
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 nashi indexi: eto nashe i: 2 eto nashe j: 2
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 nashi indexi: eto nashe i: 2 eto nashe j: 3
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 nashi indexi: eto nashe i: 2 eto nashe j: 2
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 nashi indexi: eto nashe i: 2 eto nashe j: 3
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 nashi indexi: eto nashe i: 2 eto nashe j: 2
```

И так до бесконечности...
Прошу помочь, т.к. скоро здавать а у меня совсем нет идей, где ошибка :((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Итак, все решилось и при чем достаточно просто (ошибка была тупая и из-за невнимательности):
у меня в коде выше строка для уменьшение\увеличения значения индексов массива.
Там где идет увеличение i, надо писать

```
i := i + 1
```

И все отлично сортирует :-)